# Invalid syntax with print()

Tags: python

i dont know whats the problem. please help
thank you so much
this what i did:

```
row=4
col=10
col2 = 13
L=[]
K=[]
for i in range(4,13):
   a= sheet.cell(row=10,column=i).value
   L.append(a)
for i in range(4,13):
   b= sheet.cell(row=13  ,column=i).value
   K.append(b)
print(K)
print(L)


for i in range(4,14):
    f= sheet.cell(row=14,column=i).value
a=0
b=4
while b<14:

    b+=1
    a+=1
    f= sheet.cell(row=14,column=b).value=(L[a]/(L[a] + K[b]*1.68)
print(f)
```

print(f)
 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Welcome to SO! `value=(L[a]/(L[a] + K[b]*1.68)` is missing its closing paren.

Answer (score 2):

Missing closing parentheses on the last line of while loop:

```
row=4
col=10
col2 = 13
L=[]
K=[]
for i in range(4,13):
   a= sheet.cell(row=10,column=i).value
   L.append(a)
for i in range(4,13):
   b= sheet.cell(row=13  ,column=i).value
   K.append(b)
print(K)
print(L)


for i in range(4,14):
    f= sheet.cell(row=14,column=i).value
a=0
b=4
while b < 14:
    b += 1
    a += 1
    f = sheet.cell(row=14,column=b).value=(L[a]/(L[a] + K[b]*1.68)) # <--- added parentheses here 

print(f)
```

Using an editor like vscode can help avoid this kind of thing and be a pleasure to use